# Get the date before the provided date in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, datetime

I have a bash script that receives a date as a parameter ($1) in the format YYYYMMDD

What I need to do is subtract one day from the provided date. Lets take 20130701 as an example, after processing I expect to get 20130630.

How can I do this in bash? (One line solution gets bonus points!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have GNU date:

```
$ set -- 20130701
$ yesterday=$(date -d "$1 - 1 day" "+%Y%m%d")
$ echo "$yesterday"
20130630
```